# How to transfer large file ~2GB using ActiveMQ5 without BLOB messages

Tags: activemq-classic, file-transfer

We are migrating from IBM MQ to Active MQ 5. IBM MQ supports a segmentation feature to send large files, whereas Active MQ5 supports BLOB messages but we don't want to use BLOB messages. How can we achieve segmentation using ByteMessages in ActiveMQ5 or any other alternative except BLOB messages?

When I tried to put a 100 MB file using ByteMessage I was getting a socket error.

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveMQ broker doesn't offer a built in segmentation feature so you are limited by the bounds of the JVM and the current memory allocation settings on what you can do.  Typically messages of that size are not really what JMS messaging was designed to do and other options would typically provide more robust services for send and receive of such large messages.  That being said the ActiveMQ Artemis broker does offer some support for message streaming in its Core protocol based JMS client so you could look there instead of using ActiveMQ 5.x if you choose to avoid BlobMessage.